# Sorting a list and finding an array of indices that sorts the list

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

How can I sort a list and also get a list of indices that sort this list?
For example:
primary list is a

```
a={1,4,6,7,0,2};
```

sorted list is b

```
b={7,6,4,2,1,0}
```

and also return list c

```
c={4,3,2,6,1,5}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get list `b`, you need `Sort[]`: `Sort[{1, 4, 6, 7, 0, 2}, GreaterEqual]`.

To get list `c`, you need `Ordering[]`: `Ordering[{1, 4, 6, 7, 0, 2}, All, GreaterEqual]`.

Comment: @Heike: I guess there is such a thing as being in the right place at the right time... :)

Comment: @J.M. : Thank you

Comment: Also, if you need both, you might first do `Ordering` and then `b=a[[c]]`

Comment: @Rojo: that's a good point with respect to saving sorting effort. :)